# Nested recyclerView dynamic data consistency

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, nested-lists, android-diffutils

I have vertical recyclerView with few nested horizontal recyclerView's. Each nested list updates dynamically by DiffUtils mechanism.

When i update nested list, i waited for scroll to stay in same position and new items appear on the right of it, but scroll goes on page before. What is going on?

```
class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private var nestedItems: List<Item> = emptyList()
    fun updateNestedList(items: List<Item>) {
        val diff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(...)
        nestedItems = items
        diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder() {
        when (itemType) {
            ...
            ITEM_TYPE_HORIZONTAL -> NestedListViewHolder()
        }
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            ...
            is NestedListViewHolder -> (holder as NestedListViewHolder).bind(items)
        }
    }
}

class NestedListViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private val adapter by lazy {
        NestedAdapter().apply {
            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(containerView.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, reverseLayout = false)
            contacts_list.layoutManager = layoutManager
            contacts_list.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
            contacts_list.adapter = this
        }
    }
    fun bind(items: List<Item>) {
        adapter.updateContacts(items)
    }
}

class NestedAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private var items: List<Item> = emptyList()
    fun updateItems(_items: List<Item>) {
        val diff = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(...)
        items = _items
        diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this issue, because for each nested list few ViewHolders was created. Where notifyItemChanged() called ( line diff.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)), recyclerView take cached viewHolder, call bind for him and replace already attached viewHolder.
https://android.jlelse.eu/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-continued-d81c631a2b91#.dcsykhoh9

To fix this issue i permit recyclerView reuse NestedListViewHolder.

```
    contacts_list.itemAnimator = object : DefaultItemAnimator() {
        override fun canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, payloads: MutableList<Any>): Boolean {
            return viewHolder is NestedListViewHolder || super.canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder, payloads)
        }
    }
```